# How can I select More than one option from different radio group buttons in LWC?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, javascript, html5, lightning-radiogroup

I want to select options from Radio buttons from different groups of buttons. I am only able to select only one option from all Radio button groups in the component.

[image]

[image]

in the above example, I want to select One option from the First group and another from the Second group of buttons

Answer (score 3):

For each radio group, `name` attribute should be unique.

I can make an assumption, that in your case attributes `name` are the same.

---

salesforce recommends not to set `name`, as it will be generated automatically.

> In general, we don't recommend setting the name attribute in
> lightning-radio-group. The component automatically generates a unique
> value for name if none is provided. The generated value ensures a
> common name for the  elements rendered for the radio button
> group, and is unique in the page.

```
<template>
    <lightning-radio-group label="Radio Group"
                          options={options}
                          value={value}
                          type="radio">
    </lightning-radio-group>

    <lightning-radio-group label="Radio Group"
                          options={options}
                          value={value}
                          type="radio">
    </lightning-radio-group>
</template>
```